# ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to debug a Procedure on oracle "SQL Developer "  Version 17.4.1.054. I am unable to do this as I get the following errors:

> ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
>
> ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

I did this setting in "SQL Developer" go to `'Tools' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Debugger'` and then Clicked the option for 'Prompt for debugger host for database debugging'.

But still getting the same error message.

Comment: When you get prompted, are you inputting the up address for your machine, as addressable by the DB server on the network?

Answer (score 1):

The database is trying to reach your machine.

When you get this prompt at the beginning of a debug session:

[image]

The 'debugger host' is YOUR machine. Whatever you put in there, the db is saying it can't get to your computer to start the debugger session.

[I talk more about this here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-plsql-debugger/)

Answer (score 0):

Much often it happens when database server can't reach your physical machine. Nowadays usually it happens when developer is working remotely over VPN where your computer network configuration have several IP addresses and SQL Developer pick the wrong one. In SQL Developer under *Tools -> Preferences -> Debugger* you have two choices:

1. Check DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP and choose to prompt for Debugger Host.

[image]

On debug session start you will be prompted for host IP which is **your computer IP** where SQL Developer is running.

[image]

2. If choice above doesn't work, skip DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP and use DBMS_DEBUG.

Note: [DBMS_DEBUG package is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/release-changes.html#GUID-EDBEC906-B269-4C5B-A9FE-D5AADA61532B) from Oracle database server 12.2 version and above.

[image]